# HTML to Excel data import via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

```
<div id="printing">

<div id='state'>


    <table  id="dataTable"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"   style="table-layout: fixed; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">



       <thead>

        <tr align="center" style="font-size:20px;">
            <td colspan="11"><u>Ministry of Health & Family Welfare</u></td>
            </tr>

           <tr align="center" style="font-size:20px;">
            <td colspan="11"><u>(Monitoring & Evaluation Division)</u></td>

           </tr>
           <tr align="center" style="font-size:20px;">
            <td colspan="11"><u>Monthly Format for Sub Center and Equivalent Institutions</u></td>

           </tr>
        <br></br>

        <tr align="center">
            <td>State :</td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='stateID'></td> 
            <td><td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" bgcolor="#7CFC00">Due for Submission on 5th of following Month</td>
           </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>District :</td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='districtID'>&nbsp;</td>                
            <td>Month<td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='month'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>Block :</td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='blockID'>&nbsp;</td>  
            <td>Year<td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='year'></td>

        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>City/ Town/ Village:</td>
            <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='cityID'>&nbsp;</td>             

        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
         <td>Facility name :</td>
          <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;" id='facilityID'>&nbsp;</td>               

        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td >Facility type :</td>
         <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;">
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="publicID" name="facilityType" checked><span style="font-weight: bold;">Public</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="privateID" name="facilityType" disabled><span style="font-weight: bold;">Private</span></label>


         </td>


        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td >Location :</td>
         <td style=" border:solid black 1px;width:300px;">
         <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="ruralID" name="location"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Rural</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="urbanID" name="location"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Urban</span></label></td>


        </tr>
        <tr style="height:80px;">
         <td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;">&nbsp</td>
         <td align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;">Numbers reported during the Month</td>
         <td align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;">Ref.No</td>
         <td align="center" colspan="1" width="2px;"></td>
          <td align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;">Validation Error</td>
        </tr>

         <tr style="height:35px;">
         <td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;" >Part A. REPRODUCTIVE AND CHILD HEALTH</td>            
         <td align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;" ></td>
         <td align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;" ></td>
         <td align="center" colspan="1" width="2px;" ></td>
         <td align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="yellow" style=" border:solid black 1px;" ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr  style="height:35px;"> 
        <td align="center"  bgcolor="#7CFC00"  colspan="1" style=" border:solid black 1px;"  >M1</td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#7CFC00"  colspan="6" style=" border:solid black 1px;"  >Ante Natal Care Services (ANC)</td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#7CFC00"colspan="2" style=" border:solid black 1px;" >M1</td>
         <td align="center" colspan="1" width="2px;" ></td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#7CFC00"colspan="2" style=" border:solid black 1px;" ></td>
         </tr>
     </thead>


        <tbody >

        <tr align="center" >
            <td  align="left" colspan="1"  style=" border:solid black 1px;" >1</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="4" style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;"><b> Total number of pregnant women Registered for ANC</b> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1" style=" border:solid black 1px;width:150px;" class="de" id='y72RhR0QcFn'> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="2" style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;">1.1</td>
             <td align="center" colspan="1" style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left; width:0.1px;">7|txt_Numbers_1</td>


        </tr>

<tr align="center" >
            <td align="center" colspan="1" style=" border:solid black 1px;">1.1</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="4" style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;"> <i>Of which Number registered within first trimester(within 12 weeks)</i> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1" style=" border:solid black 1px;width:150px;" class="de" id='IFYdW0qXXcy'> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="2" style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;">1.1.1</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1" style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left; width:0.1px;">7|txt_Numbers_1_1</td>
```

//this aere the formulas that i provided manually

> IF(ISBLANK(F15)*ISBLANK(F16),"",IF(F16<=G15,"","No. of pregnant women registered for ANC within 1st trimester(M1-1.1) <= No. of pregnant women registered for ANC(M1-1)"))

```
        </tr>

        <tr align="center" >
            <td align="left"    colspan="1"     style=" border:solid black 1px;">2</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="4"  style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;">Number of New women registered under Janani Suraksha Yogna</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"  style=" border:solid black 1px;width:150px;" class="de"  id='Dsam8TAhYRx'> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"> </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="2"  style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;">1.2</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"  style=" border:solid black 1px;text-align:left;" width="2px;">7|txt_Numbers_2</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"  >=IF(ISBLANK(F17)*ISBLANK(F15),"",IF(F17<=F15,"","Cross Check : Number of women registered under JSY (M1-2) <= Total number of women registered for ANC(M1-1)"))</td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: What do you want to ask???

Comment: Are you saying you want a specific file format with javascript? Copy paste, excel understands html tables...

Comment: yeap.I m building a Html report.In that report there is a button that i can download excel version ofthat  report.When download that there is a section  validation e   rrors cosist of formulas for validation.thsats the thing.  here are the links for report and excel  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0SOWMCKTJyzYU1sRFE1RnhocXM/view?usp=sharing  and  https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive

Comment: Yeap i want to build a specefic format